# Place marker based on coordinate for different screen size (Flutter)

Tags: flutter, dart, coordinates

So i have this marker widget that can be use to place at images. It will use offset to set the coordinate for x and y

```
Offset position = Offset(0.0, 0.0);
```

After that if i want to place the widget it will be something like this

```
double baseWidth = window.physicalSize.width;
double baseHeight = window.physicalSize.height;

double newWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
double newHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;

double newX = (newWidth*630)/baseWidth;
double newY = (newHeight*380)/baseHeight;

MarkerBox(
   Offset(newX, newY,
   'Box One',
   Colors.blueAccent,
   Image.asset("assets/marker_red.png",
      height: 40, width: 40, fit: BoxFit.cover),
   width / 4.5
),
```

However, if different screen size, the marker will be place differently. How do i make it static at one place regardless of what screen size? Is it because the coordinate is affected based on different screen size?

Answer (score 4):

You can get the width and height of the screen with:

- `double new_width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;`
- `double new_height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;`

And after that, you can make a [Rule of Tree](https://calcuworld.com/math/rule-of-three-calculator/). Given a "base position" called (base_x, base_y) for a "base resolution" called (base_width, base_height), you can obtain the new (new_x, new_y) for a "new resolution" given by the code above.

- `new_x = (new_width*base_x)/base_width`
- `new_y = (new_height*base_y)/base_height`

Comment: sorry but how do i get the (base_x, base_y)  & (base_width, base_height)

Comment: Thats the marker position (base_x, base_y) that you have at your actual resolution (base_width, base_height). The device that you are using to test has a resolution, and you can set the marker where you want (you said your marker is static). So, the resolution of the device is the base resolution and the position of the marker where you want, based on the testing device is the base_position.

Comment: i've done just like you mentioned (refer the question) i've edited it, however it still not static. am i doing it wrongly. i've tested it on google pixel & galaxy tab

Comment: The baseWidth and baseHeight dont have to be obtained like that. As example, imagine you will use de google pixel as "base". So, whats the resolution? Lets suppose the resolution is 480*960 (just an example, this isnt the real resolution). So, the baseWidth and baseHeight have to be hardcoded: `double baseWidth = 480;` `double baseHeight = 960;`

Comment: The trick is get the exact position you want in the "base" device, and with that values (base_resolution and base_position), convert the position in other devices to the same place that you got on you base device

Comment: Thanks a lot, I used canvas width and height instead of device size and the same formula worked there as well.